# python pandas dataframe create new column from other columns' cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this...

```
         a_return    b_return  bc_ratio instrument_holding 
0             NaN         NaN -0.165286                  a 
1        0.996474    1.013166 -0.164637                  a   
2        0.997730    0.993540 -0.170058                  a   
3        1.024294    1.024318 -0.184530                  a   
4        1.019071    1.047297 -0.148644                  a   
5        0.992243    1.008210 -0.188752                  a    
6        1.010331    1.039020 -0.098413                  a   
7        0.989542    0.991899  0.025051                  b   
8        1.005197    1.002527 -0.025051                  b 
9        0.990755    1.002352 -0.099800                  a  
10       1.006241    0.998375 -0.078643                  b
```

I want to add a column called 'log_ret' where the value from 'a_return' or 'b_return' is used based on the value in the 'instrument_holding' column. Like this...

```
         a_return    b_return  bc_ratio instrument_holding   log_ret  
0             NaN         NaN -0.165286                  a       NaN  
1        0.996474    1.013166 -0.164637                  a  0.996474  
2        0.997730    0.993540 -0.170058                  a  0.997730  
3        1.024294    1.024318 -0.184530                  a  1.024294  
4        1.019071    1.047297 -0.148644                  a  1.019071  
5        0.992243    1.008210 -0.188752                  a  0.992243  
6        1.010331    1.039020 -0.098413                  a  1.010331  
7        0.989542    0.991899  0.025051                  b  0.991899  
8        1.005197    1.002527 -0.025051                  b  1.002527  
9        0.990755    1.002352 -0.099800                  a  0.990755  
10       1.006241    0.998375 -0.078643                  b  0.998375
```

As you can see, if the row's value for 'instrument_holding' is 'a', 'log_ret' has the value from 'a_return' and if 'instrument_holding' has the value 'b', 'log_ret' has the value from 'b_return'.

I thought it could be accomplished like this...

```
df["log_ret"] = df[df["instrument_holding"] + "_return"]
```

That is not the case. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- use `map` to change values in `instrument_holding`
- use `lookup`

---

```
df.assign(
    log_return=df.lookup(df.index, df.instrument_holding.map('{}_return'.format)))

    a_return  b_return  bc_ratio instrument_holding  log_return
0        NaN       NaN -0.165286                  a         NaN
1   0.996474  1.013166 -0.164637                  a    0.996474
2   0.997730  0.993540 -0.170058                  a    0.997730
3   1.024294  1.024318 -0.184530                  a    1.024294
4   1.019071  1.047297 -0.148644                  a    1.019071
5   0.992243  1.008210 -0.188752                  a    0.992243
6   1.010331  1.039020 -0.098413                  a    1.010331
7   0.989542  0.991899  0.025051                  b    0.991899
8   1.005197  1.002527 -0.025051                  b    1.002527
9   0.990755  1.002352 -0.099800                  a    0.990755
10  1.006241  0.998375 -0.078643                  b    0.998375
```

Comment: Very interesting approach!

Answer (score 8):

One possibility would be to use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) on the condition wherein *instrument_holding* equals `"a"` and returning the corresponding value in the *a_return* column if the condition is satisfied, else the other column.

Use [`DF.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to make the assignment to a new column, *log_ret* later.

```
df.assign(log_ret=np.where(df.instrument_holding == 'a', df.a_return, df.b_return))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `apply`. This is not the most magical way, but it's very flexible.

```
def select(row):
    if row['instrument_holding'] == 'a':
        return row['a_return']
    else:
        return row['b_return']

df['log_ret'] = df.apply(select, axis=1)
```